# Сделать рамку под изображение с фигурами

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, design

Может кто знает как можно реализовать обрамляющую рамку для изображения, куда в дальнейшем через админку будет добавлена фотография.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой промежуточный результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.shaped {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .shaped {
    min-width: 400px;
  }
}
.shaped__decor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.shaped__decor-elems {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f9f9f9 0%, #fff 35%, rgba(0,212,255,0) 100%);
}
.shaped__decor-elems:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;
}
.shaped__decor-elems:last-child {
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shaped" style="background-image: url('/local/templates/ilab/img/inside-page/rukovodstvo/avatar.png')">
    
    <div class="shaped__decor">
        <div class="shaped__decor-elems"></div>
        <div class="shaped__decor-elems"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

пробовал уже и псевдо-элементами, и отдельный блок с дивами. Как котыль собрать то проблем вообще не вижу, но если добавить реальное фото, то получается полный ПЭ.. Может кто сталкивался с таким вот дизайнерским чудом?
P.S. Попросили продемонстрировать попытки свои. Откорректировал с добавлением разметки и стилей.

Comment: Почему не показываете ваши попытки? Здесь так принято.

Comment: Извините. Теперь показываю.

Comment: Тут есть фрагмент кода, конвертируйте ваш scss в css и добавьте через него.

Comment: А что такое `обрамляюшая рамка` подскажите?

Comment: Изображение прямоугольное, то что должно ему скруглять углы и добавлять элемент с вырезом спрпава. Это я впредполагаю "обрамляющей рамкой".

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dywRYeN - обычный clip-path css, рисуем в векторе и берём path и вставляем его в https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path, в моём случае я нарисовал на угад и потому увеличивать фото через scale

Comment: Спасибо большое! до этого не приходилось сталкиваться со свойством clip-path. Очень весьма полезная штука оказалась.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MWZobLX - хотя вот этот пример просто удобнее

Comment: Согласен. Но мне надо еще играть с этим элементом, ротому как на разных разрешениях он изменяться будет; где-то смещаться, где-то высоту менять, на разных брейкпойнтах в общем будет своя песня. Спасибо  еще раз! Сам бы точно не допер.

Comment: Надеюсь я хотя бы хоть чем то помог...удачи

Comment: Очень помог! спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей подойдет mask-image

```css
.mask {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  background-image: url('https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/fxAcjsArmKoR4jmB45QRD/a8778010f3d0ceb13c02d21194abd99a/Stock-photo-composition_featured-1.webp');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-image: url('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/37/37598.png');
  mask-image: url('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/37/37598.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="mask"></div>
```

Для масштабируемой маски можно использовать svg

Также почитайте про `mask-mode: luminance;` если в планах использовать черно-белую маску

Comment: О, супер! Тоже очень пригодится! Спасибо!